# How do I represent the directed graph given below and traverse BFS and DFS algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

How do I represent the directed graph given below and traverse the following graph using the Breadth-first search (BFS) and depth-first search (DFS) algorithm?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0at9.jpg)

Comment: Add your current approach as well

Comment: Use adjacency lists.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Graph can be represented as adjacency list or adjacency matrix. Use adjacency list and use queue for BFS and do recursion for dfs maintaining a visited. Since you haven't provide any code only the simple logic can be given